# Gedmo Loggable extension: add a new column to entries

Tags: symfony, doctrine, stofdoctrineextensions, gedmo-loggable

I have an application with products and attributes. In the backoffice I would like to track the changes on the attribute values. I started using loggable extension by gedmo and it works fine but now I'd like to add a new column in the log entry table for the product id.
I know how to create a custom entity for the logs by adding the annotation in the attribute table:

```
@Gedmo\Loggable(logEntryClass="App\Entity\LogEntry")
```

But I don't know if is somehow possible to extend the Gedmo listener to also log the product_id in the log entry table

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/advanced.html#overriding-the-listeners

With this its easy to use a custom logger